# 'Could not load Microsoft.VisualBasic.Tristate' in ASP .NET Core Application

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-core

I'm new to .NET Core and I'm having some issues referencing a DLL written in VB.NET.

I'm getting this exception:

`Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.TriState' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.`

When attempting to use a class from said DLL.

I've also got the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` package installed via NuGet.

Any ideas of what I could try?

Comment: It looks like the library you are using may not support the appropriate .Net Standard that is needed to loaded in an .Net Core application... You can look at Hans's comment on that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897920/how-to-reference-microsoft-visualbasic-in-a-net-standard-class-library